# regex only very specific match with two similar URLs before the capture

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

So I'm trying to pull just the name of a certain images with the image extension captured along with it. The only problem is that there are two very similar forms and two forms only of the way the image url is displayed.

The first url is diplayed something like this

```
http://www.trollface.com/dolan/images/IMGnameEYEwant.jpg
```

The only problem is that occasionally the image is display this way as well:

```
http://www.trollface.com/dolan/images/small/IMGnameEYEwant.jpg
```

Now I know this is not elegant by any means but something like this is what I have to been using:

```
trollface\.com/dolan/images/(.*?)">
```

This has been working fine up until now because of how similar the two URLs are

Another problem is that **I need the solution to be pure regex. No java, php, javascript nothing.** Even tried to literally have it try every letter combination before hand like this, which again I know is extremely bad methodology but I'm a regex noob:

```
[ao][gr]e[s/][/i][pm][ra][og][de][us][c/][tp][/r][so][md][au][lc][lt]/(.*?)">
```

Only problem with this is that it will always find the first URL first because of how similar they are and will also always capture the `small/` part of the URL which I DONT NEED.

How would I do this? I was thinking maybe a lookahead or lookbehind, but I'm not experienced enough to get those to work.

**EDIT:** core is Java based but in the current situation, I cannot use Java to aid with this problem :(

Comment: The language you're doing this in is kind of crucial.

Comment: Edited to fix this, but it won't make a difference I believe because I won't be able to manipulate the java code. I guess the formatting would be a little different so that could be important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#http://www.trollface.com/dolan/images/(?:small/)?([^/\#]+)#
```

An explanation of the regular expression, after the literal match:

```
(?: ... )
```

a Non capturing group.  Meaning "match this, but don't pass it back."

```
... ?
```

Make the previous group optional.

```
(  ... )
```

A capturing group

```
[^/\#]+
```

any character that is not a forward slash or a hash tag, one or more times.  You may not need to escape this in Java.

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you for the great explanation too! Will accept your answer when it lets me in three minutes! Will definitely be using the `(?: ... )?` in the future. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
var test1="http://www.trollface.com/dolan/images/IMGnameEYEwant.jpg";
var test2="http://www.trollface.com/dolan/images/small/IMGnameEYEwant.jpg";
var test3="http://google.com/";

var rx = /(http:\/\/www\.trollface\.com\/dolan\/images\/)(?:small)?(.+)/i;

var m = test1.match(rx);
if(m.length == 3) {
    alert(m[1]);
    alert(m[2]);
}
var m = test2.match(rx);
if(m.length == 3) {
    alert(m[1]);
    alert(m[2]);
}
var m = test3.match(rx);
if(m.length == 3) {
    alert(m[1]);
    alert(m[2]);
}
```

Comment: This solution would work If I could actually use any java, but at this moment I cannot. Thanks for the answer though! All the additional info has got to be helping someone! (/^_^)/